# Floating point anomaly when an unused statement is not commented out?

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, floating-point

When the program as shown below is run, it produces ok output:

```
 j=         0    9007199616606190.000000 = x
 k=         0    9007199616606190.000000 = [x]
 r=  31443101                   0.000000 = m*(x-[x])
```

But when the commented-out line (*i.e.* `//if (argc>1) r = atol(argv[1]);`) is uncommented, it produces:

```
 j=     20000    9007199616606190.000000 = x
 k=     17285    9007199616606190.000000 = [x]
 r=  31443101                   0.000000 = m*(x-[x])
```

even though that line should have no effect, since `argc>1` is false.  Has anybody got a plausible explanation for this problem?  Is it reproducible on any other systems?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int  j, k, m=10000;
   double r=31443101, jroot=sqrt(83), x;
   //if (argc>1) r = atol(argv[1]);
   x = r * r * jroot;
   j = m*(x-floor(x));
   k = floor(m*(x-floor(x)));
   printf ("j= %9d   %24.6f = x\n", j, x);
   printf ("k= %9d   %24.6f = [x]\n", k, floor(x));
   printf ("r= %9.0f   %24.6f = m*(x-[x]) \n", r, m*(x-floor(x))); 
   return 0;
 }
```

Note, test system = AMD Athlon 64 5200+ system with Linux 2.6.35.14-96.fc14.i686 (*i.e.*, booted to run a 32-bit OS on 64-bit HW) with gcc (GCC) 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4)

**Update --** A few hours ago I posted a comment that code generated with and without the `if` statement differed only in stack offsets and some skipped code.  I now find that comment was not entirely correct; *i.e.* it is true for non-optimized code, but not true for the -O3 code I executed.

**Effect of optimization switch on problem:**

- -O0 : Both program versions run ok
- -O2 or -O3 : Version with comment has error as above, where `j=20000` and `k=17285`
- -O1 : Version with comment has `j=20000` (an error) and `k=0` (OK)

Anyhow, looking at -O3 -S code listings, the two cases differ mostly in skipped `if` code and stack offsets up to the line before `call floor`, at which point the with-if code has one more `fstpl` than the without-if code:

```
    ...  ;; code without comment:
fmul    %st, %st(1)
fxch    %st(1)
fstpl   (%esp)
fxch    %st(1)
fstpl   48(%esp)
fstpl   32(%esp)
call    floor
movl    $.LC2, (%esp)
fnstcw  86(%esp)
movzwl  86(%esp), %eax
    ...
    ...  ;; versus code with comment:
fmul    %st, %st(1)
fxch    %st(1)
fstpl   (%esp)
fxch    %st(1)
fstpl   48(%esp)
fstpl   32(%esp)
fstpl   64(%esp)
call    floor
movl    $.LC3, (%esp)
fnstcw  102(%esp)
movzwl  102(%esp), %eax
    ...
```

I haven't figured out the reason for the difference.

Comment: That code produces the same output -- regardless of whether that line is commented out or not -- on both my Linux and OS X systems.

Comment: Not reproducible for me; `j=0` and `k=0` on runs with and without the commented line. Ubuntu 11.04, `gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)`, Intel Core i7 920 (family 6, model 26, stepping 4). (64 bit OS and userland.)

Comment: I get the former result both ways on my Mac OS box. And with several different versions of gcc from 4.0 through 4.6. It's beginning to look like it might be something particular to your situation.

Comment: I can't reproduce that problem with the *exact* same version of `gcc`, albeit with gcc itself compiled as an x86-64 binary (using `-m32` to compile a 32-bit target of course).

Comment: @jwpat7, you should show _all_ of the assembly code for both cases.

Comment: It amounts to ~ 300 lines of code, so I didn't include all in the question.  But see full listings at [fp-anomaly link](http://pat7.com/jw/fp-anomaly/) for -O0, -O1, -O3 cases, with the *if* line in and out.  Can add object files or executables if you like.

Answer (score 3):

Not duplicated on my system, Win7 running CygWin with gcc 4.3.4. Both with and without the `if` statement, the value of `j` is set to zero, not 20K.

My only suggestion would be to use `gcc -S` to get a look at the assembler output. That should hopefully tell you what's going wrong.

Specifically, generate the assembler output to two separate files, one each for the working and non-working variant, then vgrep them (eyeball them side by side) to try and ascertain the difference.

---

This is a serious failure in your environment by the way. With `m` being 10000, that means the `x - floor(x)` must be equal to 2. I can't for the life of me think of any real number where that would be the case :-)

Comment: I diff'd the files, and the differences are:  (1) several stack access offsets are 8 more with the `if` in, and (2) 10 lines of code for the atol() call, jumped around by a `jle .L2`.  I'm going to try the code on my other systems...

Comment: See Update re code diff when appropriate switches are used :)

Answer (score 2):

The reason that uncommenting that line *might* affect the result is that without that line, the compiler can see that `r` and `jroot` cannot change after initialisation, so it can calculate `x` at compile-time rather than runtime.  When the line is uncommented, `r` might change, so the calculation of `x` must be deferred to runtime, which can result it in being done with a different precision (particularly if 387 floating point math is being used).

You can try using `-mfpmath=sse -march=native` to use the SSE unit for floating point calculations, which doesn't exhibit excess precision; or you can try using the `-ffloat-store` switch.

Your subtraction `x - floor(x)` exhibits catastrophic cancellation - this is <strike>the root cause of the problem</strike> something to be avoided ;).

Comment: +1 for first paragraph, but your last paragraph is incorrect.  True, "catastrophic cancellation" occurs, but it isn't the root cause, which seems to be a mistake in gcc optimization (see my Update to question)

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two reasons why that line could have an effect:

- Without that line, the values of all of these variables can be (and, IMHO, most likely *are*) determined at compile-time; with that line, the computations have to be performed at run-time. But obviously, the compiler's precomputed values are supposed to be the same as values computed at run-time, and I'm inclined to discount this as the actual reason for the different observed behavior. (It would certainly show up as a huge difference in the assembler output, though!)
- On many machines, floating-point arithmetic is performed using more bits in intermediate values than can actually be stored in a double-precision floating-point number. Your second version, by creating two different code-paths to set `x`, basically restricts `x` to what *can* be stored in a double-precision floating-point number, whereas your first version can allow the initially-calculated value for `x` to still be available as an intermediate value, with extra bits, when computing subsequent values. (This could be the case whether all of these values are computed at compile-time or at run-time.)

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

I also do not see a difference when I compile your code on my computer using the -O0, -O1, -O2 and -O3.

AMD Phenom Quad 64 bit.
gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3

I also tried clang (llvm) from release 3.0 with and without the if same results.

I agree that the compiler can pre-compute everything without that if line, you would definitely see that in the assembly output though.

Floating point and C can be nasty, lots of stuff to know to get it to really work.  Forcing the int to double conversions is good for accuracy (c libraries in the compiler, even if the fpu is good have been known to have problems and the compilers C library it uses and the C library compiled into or used by your program can/will differ), but int to/from float is where FPU's tend to have their bugs (I think I saw that mentioned with TestFloat or somewhere like that).  Might try running TestFloat on your system to see if your FPU is good.  Between the famous pentium floating point bug and into the PentiumIV and beyond days most processors had floating point bugs, the pentium III I had was solid but the Pentium IV I had would fail.  I rarely use floating point anymore so dont bother to test my systems.

Playing with optimization did change your results according to your edit so this is most likely a gcc problem or a combination of your code and gcc (and not a hardware fpu problem).   Then try a different version of gcc on the same computer.  4.4.x instead of 4.5.x for example.

Comment: Format %lf made no difference and I didn't expect it to because in `man 3 printf` one reads: "f, F   The *double* argument is rounded and converted to decimal notation ..." without mention of float, and also reads "l (ell) A following integer conversion..." (or n, c, or s conversion) without mention of float or double.